# How do I disable the browse button in Telerik MVC Upload control after a file is uploaded?

Tags: upload, telerik-mvc

I need a condition where I want to upload only one document using the Telerik MVC upload control. I have already set the "Multiple(false)" property set in Telerik control.

Once the file is uploaded, I want only the "Browse" button to be disabled. I have alteady tried disabling the entire upload control. In this case the remove button also gets disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't as easy as it should be. However, you can do this by handling the `onSuccess` event of the upload control and using jQuery to find the `span` in which the upload button resides and use `attr("disabled", "disabled")` to disable its contents:

**Upload control:**

```
<%= Html.Telerik().Upload()
        .Name("document")

        //add a custom attribute
        .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "myCustomClass" })

        .Async(async => async
            .Save("Save", "Home")
            .Remove("Remove", "Home")
        )
        .ClientEvents(events => events
            .OnSuccess("onSuccess")
        )
%>
```

**JavaScript event handler:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onSuccess(e) {
        $(".myCustomClass").find('span:first').attr("disabled", 'disabled');
    }
</script>
```